# iOS 5 UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible closes modal

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiwindow

I have a scenario where I present a modal view controller from the main window's rootViewController. While it is loading the contents of this modal, I am switching to another loading window which I make key and visible.

This window acts as a loading indicator and does not allow the user to interact with the app. When it is done loading, I switch back to the main window by making it key and visible. When I do this, the modal is force closed and the app is no longer able to present modals.

Interestingly enough, if I execute [UIWindow makeKeyWindow] when switching back to the main window, there are no issues. [UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] is what's causing the issue. Is [UIWindow makeKeyWindow] an acceptable alternative?

This is iOS 5 only. No issues in iOS 6. I am not supporting iOS 4. Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Comment: you should not use more then one window, except for other displays like vga out

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior.  Have you just decided to use makeKeyWindow and everything is okay?

Comment: Bastian, would you be able to elaborate on why its not good practice to use more than one window. I don't see anything in the docs that states an app must or should only have one window. The UIWindow class reference states, "Unless an app can display content on an external device screen, an app has only one window."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same behaviour, and as documentation states that `makeKeyAndVisible` method is *a convenience method* it seems to me legit to substitute `makeKeyAndVisible` call with working code:

```
[window makeKeyWindow];
window.hidden = NO;
```

Have no idea what's wrong, but it looks like a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I attempted the above and all looks okay!

Answer (score 0):

It is definetly bug in iOS 5 UIWindow implemetation. I faced this strange behaviour and Aleksey's answer is the way to go.